# Can I use `reverse` to reverse a number in ruby? If not, how do I do so?

Tags: ruby

I would like to reverse a number. I don't think `reverse` works. Is there a way? And why would it not work?

Comment: Fire a rails console (`rails c`) and try to use `.reverse` on an Integer; for example, `12345.reverse `. You'll see `undefined method reverse`. You could test this before asking this question. If I understood what you want, you should simply convert your number to string and then reverse it. Like `12345.to_s.reverse`

Comment: @sandre89 there is nothing about rails, it's ruby question.

Comment: Reverse a *number*? Huh? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: You could just do it mathematically, like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480068/how-to-reverse-digits-of-an-integer-mathematically

Comment: Great idea, Brad! Love it.

Comment: What do you mean by reversing a number? Explain that. For `3`, do you want `-3`, `1/3`, or perhaps something else?

Comment: @sawa probably `Ɛ` ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Try These

```
123456.to_s.reverse.to_i
```

Or If your using `ruby version 2.4` than you can try these aslo

```
123456.digits.join.to_i
```

Comment: I just noticed your second solution, which I gave as my answer well after.you posted it, so I’ve deleted my answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

`. reverse` is a method for strings so it won't work directly on an integer or float. You just need to momentarily turn your number into string, apply the method and and just turn it back to integer/float.
Just use `num.to_s.reverse.to_i` for **integers** or `num.to_s.reverse.to_f` for **floats**

Comment: Thank you Dimitrios and Ig86